# Switched from Zend to Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans-7

I switched IDE's from Zend Studio to net beans and I found that everything in Net beans is tabbed 8 spaces. is there away to mass fix this, the "format" under source, formats my code in such a way that it looks bad.

what are the steps to set your own formatting rules and to fix tab indentation in net beans?

Comment: You probably get better answers, if you post this on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @Lion from the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) `if your question generally covers ... software tools commonly used by programmers` - I think an IDE falls within that category of questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tab size & co can be tuned via Tools-->Options-->Editor-->Formatting

You can opt to change that setting for all languages, or make specific settings for PHP with the "Language" dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

you have to go in option->editor->formatting and there you can set the "tab size"